# Cannot get user info with Google Identity Services

Tags: google-signin, google-authentication

Well, I'm integrating the Google Identity Services into my application. But it doesn't run.
I'm following the instruction give in https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web

So I added these lines into the head of the `index.html` file

```html
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_GOOGLE_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

and these at the beginning of the body:

```js
    <script>
      function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        console.log('hello, world');
        console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
      }
      window.onload = function () {
      
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: 'MY_GOOGLE_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
          callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });
        
        // Display the One Tap prompt
        google.accounts.id.prompt();
        
        // Display the Sign In With Google Button
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
          { theme: 'outline', size: 'large' }
        );
      }
      </script>
```

Then added this line into my `Navbar.js`

```html
<li className='nav-item'>
  <div id="buttonDiv" class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</li>
```

As far as I understood, when the user correctly sign-in, the `handleCredentialResponse` callback should be called by Google, but nothing appeared on my console.log.

I can login correctly, using different credentials. The user image and email address appear into the button, but I'm not notified of the event.

I tried to follow the instruction, but seems that Google suggest these new approach referred in the link at the top, but the instruction still are for the old implementation.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

So when you initialise the button in your  tag, it will have a "data-callback" parameter. Pass your handler in that like below.

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
      <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
         **data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"**
         data-login_uri="https://your.domain/your_login_endpoint"
         data-auto_prompt="false">
      </div>
      <div class="g_id_signin"
         data-type="standard"
         data-size="large"
         data-theme="outline"
         data-text="sign_in_with"
         data-shape="rectangular"
         data-logo_alignment="left">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```